# Can the main home page of Visual Studio Online be customized?

Tags: azure-devops

*Sorry if this shouldn't be asked, I'm not sure if it falls under SO's allowed questions.*

The home page of Visual Studio Online is pretty bland and filled with "ads" for the additional features that VSO and Microsoft offer. Is it possible to customize this page? I know individual accounts have custom dashboards, but can the root level home page be edited at all? I can't find any info regarding this anywhere.

Comment: [Dashboards](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2015-oct-30-vso)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the page can be customized. And the customization for the dashboards is for whole team rather than individual account. Only team admins can add or modify it. Refer to this link for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Report/dashboards

By the way, the Welcome Portal under Home page can be customized too. Refer to this link for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/overview/reference/markdown-guidance

Comment: I apologize for not being clear--I mean the MAIN home page. Your first link I know about, but it's the home page for each individual project/solution. I'm trying to customize the actual home page, the page that's just `subdomain.visualstudio.com`.

Comment: This page cannot be customized for now.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the homepage of a team project (`https://<yourtenant>.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/<yourproject>`) this can be customized using the new [Dashboards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Report/dashboards) feature.

The homepage of the tenant (`https://<yourtenant>.visualstudio.com`) cannot be customized at the moment, except that you can hide certain modules, but this will only be for you.